# Error when If_Else used in triggers

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers, insert

Please refer the below image

[image]

I want to create an `After Insert` trigger on `Ongoing_Fees` table where it updates the `VAT` table. However before it insert data to the VAT table, it should check whether the `VAT` field of the particular `Portfolio` is `true`. `Ongoing_Fees` table has the `foreign key` access to the `Portfolio` table, so it can access the related portfolio.

Below is what I have tried

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `Ongoing_Fees_AINS` AFTER INSERT ON `Ongoing_Fees` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE `vat` Boolean;
`vat` = SELECT VAT from Portfolio WHERE Portfolio.idPortfolio = New.idPortfolio;

IF (`vat` == true) THEN
    INSERT INTO VAT VALUES (100, current_Timestamp, New.idPortfolio, New.idOngoing_Fees)
END;
```

But of course, it has an error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= SELECT VAT from Portfolio WHERE Portfolio.idPortfolio = New.idPortfolio;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `Ongoing_Fees_AINS` AFTER INSERT ON `Ongoing_Fees`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE `_vat` BOOL;
  SET `_vat` := (SELECT `VAT` FROM `Portfolio` WHERE `Portfolio`.`idPortfolio` = NEW.`idPortfolio`);    
  IF (`_vat` = TRUE) THEN
    INSERT INTO `VAT` (
         `Amount`,
         `current_timestamp`,
         `Portfolio_idPortfolio`,
         `Ongoing_Fees_idOngoing`
    )
    VALUES (
         100,
         CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
         NEW.`idPortfolio`,
         NEW.`idOngoing_Fees`
    );
  END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

A shorter version:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `Ongoing_Fees_AINS` AFTER INSERT ON `Ongoing_Fees`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `VAT` (
         `Amount`,
         `current_timestamp`,
         `Portfolio_idPortfolio`,
         `Ongoing_Fees_idOngoing`
    )
    SELECT
         100,
         CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
         NEW.`idPortfolio`,
         NEW.`idOngoing_Fees`
    FROM
         DUAL
    WHERE
         TRUE = (SELECT
                      `VAT`
                 FROM
                      `Portfolio`
                 WHERE
                      `Portfolio`.`idPortfolio` = NEW.`idPortfolio`
                );
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: The syntax of `IF` is `IF ... THEN ... END IF`. I see that renaming of the variable is done, because local variables should not have the same name as tables or columns.